# Postman: This seems to be like an error connecting to localhost:3000. The response status was 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, postman

I wrote this web Api and wrote first route on root i.e on *localhost:3000/ or just /* that will return a document from mongodb (I dont know If we can do this that get on "/") like this:

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res) {

quizz.findOne({ id: 1}, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
  console.log(err)
} else {
  console.log(data);
  res.json(data);
}
})})
```

and I'm requesting from client like this:

```
 this.http.get('https://localhost:3000/data').map(function (res) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body.body || {};
 }).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
 })
```

but I'm getting this when I'm clicking on button(that actually has method inside which there is request method) Im getting this:

[image]

Also tried postman getting this error:

This seems to be like an error connecting to http://localhost:3000/. The response status was 0.

Comment: It appears that your client is running on port 3001. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes the client is running on 3001, and server on 3000

Comment: Can you share the server bootstrap code too? And how do you serve the client running on port 3000?

Comment: Please show your original `request-method`!

Comment: My mistake actually the server hosting client side using static middleware like this app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./../client"))); and there is also route on root like I showed in question, so when I'm hitting localhost:3000 after running server so because of route on "/" the browser keeps loading, and when I'm commenting out that route i.e app.get("/", ..) the client serves through static middleware normally.

Comment: @mxii the request method is just the http.get that I showed in question, there is nothing else except this

Comment: Ok, was confused a bit: `look LIKE this`.. and inside of that error message: `URL null`.. You should be able to `GET` that via browser too?

Comment: I dont know why URL is null you can see the way I'm requesting